# Conditional ordering for multiple columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Post model and a View model (which logs the view of each post by a user) as follows:

```
class View < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :post, :class_name => 'Post'
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope =>:post_id
end
```

Each post has a boolean field named "special".

I want to fetch all posts with following sort conditions:

1. If a post is 'special' AND NOT VIEWED by the current user (say user_id=2), then that should appear on top in the result, internally sorted by id in descending order).
2. Sort all other posts (not special and viewed-special) on the basis of id field for the posts.

Cant figure out if and how I can do that.

To start with, I tried the following query:

```
posts = Post.order("(case when special = true then 'special desc, id desc' else 'id desc' end)")
```

But it behaves in a funny manner: returns all special posts in top followed by regular posts but with ids sorted in ascending order.

What am i missing here? Also, how can I use join (for views table) with such a complex order by clause? I tried to write a SQL for this but struggling there also! Show me some light :)

P.S I'm new to Rails and still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is, for each row computing one of 2 string literals and ordering based on that which is why you don't get the examples you want. 
I'd do something like

```
Post.order('special desc, id desc')
```

Since rails stores boolean fields as 0/1 in MySQL this will sort special posts ahead of non special posts.

Adding views to this doesn't change a whole lot: you need to left join the views table and do something like

```
Post.joins('left join views on posts.id=post_id and user_id=2').order(' ( views.id is null && special)  desc, id desc')
```

The `is null` detects whether a view was found which is then and-ed with the post's specialness.

Comment: Thanks Frederick. That solved my problem. (Except a small edit: desc in the order by expression).